# Issue in passing argument via jenkins to shell script

Tags: python, bash, docker, jenkins

I have a remote machine X.X.X.X, This remote machine has docker which has the script inside it like below

```
docker exec -i $docker_container_id python /test/script.py $param1 $param2 /host/test/
```

It is executed successfully when I run this from the remote machine

I have jenkins running in my local machine, I am trying to execute the same command in remote machine

Steps I followed,

1) Created a freestyle project
2) This is a parameterized project and selected the three strings docker_container_id, param1, param2
3) "pre build shell script" section has the following script

```
echo $docker_container_id
        docker exec -i $docker_container_id python /test/script.py $param1 $param2 /host/test/
```

echo is printed with container Id, But the parameters are not fetched, rather I get this error

```
echo $docker_container_id 
docker exec -i $docker_container_id python /host/base/ci/src/automated_tests.py $param1 $param2 /host/test/
test_container_id
```

1) So the parameters are not passed inside the docker command but it is working for the 'echo'

2) When I try with the below command (i.e) double quote parameters are passed but I get the below error,

```
"docker exec -i $docker_container_id python /test/script.py $param1 $param2 /host/test/"
```

Error :

```
echo $docker_container_id 
"docker exec -i base_test python /host/base/ci/src/automated_tests.py $BRANCH $DATE /host/base/"
bash: line 4: docker exec -i test_container_id python /host/base/ci/src/automated_tests.py param1 param2 /host/test/: No such file or directory
test
```

Surprisingly now arguments are passed but I get the error "No such file or directory"

Comment: Did you try: `docker exec -i "$docker_container_id" python /test/script.py "$param1" "$param2" /host/test/` ?

Comment: @Sers It is not working, still it is using the parameter field '$param1'

Comment: Try with escape : `docker exec -i "\$docker_container_id" python /test/script.py "\$param1" "\$param2" /host/test/`.

Comment: No still the same :(

Comment: with `docker exec -i docker_container_id "python /app/pyargs.py $param1 $param2 /host/test/"` it look for `param1` on host, not inside container.  also your command does not seems correct, use bash with exec `docker_container_id`. to deal with both value try `export param1=test && export param2=test2 && docker exec -i $docker_container_id bash -c "python /app/pyargs.py $param1 $param2 /host/test"`

Comment: @Adii, I tried this already and end up with $param1 passed as string again but If I echo $param1, It is printing test1

Comment: are you running this in Jenkins execute shell?

Comment: if working with echo then use this workaround. `export param2=test && docker exec -i test bash -c "python /test/script.py $param1 $(echo $param2) /host/test"`

Comment: @adii yes - Pre Build Script in Jenkins

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201829/discussion-between-adiii-and-harry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `docker exec -i docker_container_id "python /app/test.py $param1 $param2 /host/test/"` it look for `$param1` on host, not inside container. also your command does not seems correct, use bash with exec docker_container_id. to deal with both value try

```
export param1=test && export param2=test2 && docker exec -i $docker_container_id bash -c "python /app/test.py $param1 $param2 /host/test"
```

Also, double-check the Jenkins execute shell, is it passing the variable and docker able to expend these variables from Jenkins params. if there is issue in expension pass them as ENV to docker exec command.

```
docker exec -e BRANCH=$BRANCH -i base_test bash -c "python /app/test.py $BRANCH $DATE /host/base/"
```

Also, you can direct ssh command with out ssh-pluging.

[image]

one last thing, double-check the value in script instead of Jenkins UI.

As from the discussion we also point out it was Jenkins display problem and the value properly expended in a container so better to check at script.